# How to split sublists of single list in python using split function?

Tags: python, list

I have a single list and there is multiple sublists so the question is how to split them using split. I can do it using for loop and I think it is a little longer process.

Here is the python code

```
list =[["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"],[1,2,3]]

separate = list.split(",")
```

Here is another way

```
list =[["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"],[1,2,3]]

separate_one, separate_two, separate_three  = list.split(",") 

print(separate_one)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing about string and instruction symbol.

Here is what you want.

```
my_list = [["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"],[1,2,3]]

a, b, c = my_list

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

the split function will be used as like this

```
my_string = "I'am, a, monster!"
a, b, c = my_string.split(",")

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```